# Spark streaming mapWithState timeout without remove

Tags: spark-streaming

Imagine a use case where events are streaming in per user but only the first week of events are of interest. Within that time frame stateful logic is taking place using mapWithState. After that period the user incoming events should be disregarded.

As the user's state takes memory, it makes sense to change it after the user's week period to a simple already-seen-marker.

If any event comes in for that user a week or later after his first event, it is easy to change the state to that already-seen-marker.

But, if no events come after that week, the state never changes to that already-seen-marker, and the state will continue to occupy memory forever.

As far as I understand, adding a timeout ( to user's state ) will not help, as you are not allowed to change state for a timeout state ( makes sense, as it is going to be removed ).

Is there a simple way to achieve this use case?

Comment: *As far as I understand, adding a timeout ( to user's state ) will not help, as you are not allowed to change state for a timeout state ( makes sense, as it is going to be removed ).* Can you elaborate what you mean by that? If the state has timed out, that means that no new event has come in for the period defined.

Comment: It is true that a timeout means no new events came in for that user for a week, but it also means the state will be removed for that user, meaning that the next event that comes in for him will mistakenly be considered his first event ever. What I would like is instead of the state to be removed, have it updated to an already-seen-marker. Not sure current API supports this use case though...

Comment: So basically what you want is a deduplicate mechanism? If a user has been seen, you want to discard all his data going forward?

Comment: Events coming after the first week should be discarded, yes.

Comment: I currently have 2 ideas to solve the problem: 1) to random generate a few fake user events ( with random user ids ) and union them to the batch ( so every user is guaranteed to get some event after the first week ). 2) To have two mapWithState, first only for expiration handling, whose output will be union'ed to the batch as well. Just wondering if there is a more natural way

Comment: But what happens when you need to upgrade your spark job and have to delete the state? Do you save snapshots? Because it seems like you're going to be holding the state infinitely, which doesn't sound like a good idea. I would flush the events after a week, write them to a persistent store, and then use a `filter` phase before `mapWithState` to only update user ids that don't have the "already-seen" marker set.

Comment: On startup, the StateSpec will be initialized from an rdd holding all the previously-encountered users. Their state will start with the marker from the beginning. At least that's the idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148171/discussion-between-yuval-itzchakov-and-harel).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, Spark's 2.2 mapGroupsWithState has richer timeouts that can be used not only to remove a state, but also to change it (check [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17179)).